# Baucis - router documents method not found

Tags: node.js, express, baucis

I'm working on a new project and I'm new with baucis for node.js. This is the code:

```
var name = 'order'
  , baucis = require('baucis')
  , controller = baucis.rest(name)
  , paths = config.paths;

controller.request(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) 
    return next();
  return res.send(401);
});

controller.documents(function (req, res, next) {
  if (typeof req.baucis.documents === 'number') return next();
  [...]
  next();
});
```

And this is the error:

```
/Users/fil/[...]/order.js:31
controller.documents(function (req, res, next) {
           ^
TypeError: Object function router(req, res, next) {
    router.handle(req, res, next);
  } has no method 'documents'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/fil/[...]/order.js:31:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at /Users/fil/[...]/app.js:29:5
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/fil/[...]/app.js:27:57)
```

Any idea of the reason why this happends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say 100% for sure, but I am guessing you are trying to use the `controller.documents` method with a new version of baucis, one that does not support this middleware stage.

If this is so, read about using outgoing stream transforms in the `README.md` file.

HTH